# Пути компиляции less

Tags: less

Установил less через npm
При сохранении файла .less автоматом создается файл .css в той же директории, что не есть гуд.
Как настроить путь к папке куда будут сохраняться файлы .css при компиляции
Использую Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря как запускаете less.
Если less запускается из консоли как отдельная команда `lessc styles.less > styles.css`. То просто указываете путь после `>`.
Если используется система сборки gulp/grunt/webpack, то путь указывается внутри задач.

Comment: Говорю, что автоматом компиляция происходит после сохранения, ни использую ни тот ни другой Ваш вариант

Comment: Можно увидеть код? Используется ли какой нибудь редактор? У Вас наверника стоит watch на файл, просто так он не мог появится.

Comment: Sublime  может это он делает

Comment: А какой код Вам нужен

Comment: В таком случаи код не нужен, я почти уверен что у Вас стоит плагин для компиляции less в css при сохранении, например [этот](https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-less2css). Попробуйте в настройках редактора посмотреть установленные плагины и посмотреть нет ли там связанного с less. Я к сожалению плохо знаю sublime, т.к. пользуюсь phpstorm

Comment: Понял, спасибо огромное

Comment: Нашел, вы были правы